# How grouping not happening here?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is wrong with this code?

```
Select Distinct(Output), Max(x.Senddate)
  From Url_Response x
 Where Upper(x.Output) Not Like '%SUCCESS%'
 Group By Distinct(Output)
 Order By 1 Desc;
```

Comment: What is `Distinct(Output)`?

Answer (score 2):

`group by` automatically produces one row per distinct permutation of the grouping columns. So your use of `distinct` is redundant as well as syntactically invalid.

```
 Select x.Output, Max(x.Senddate) 
 From Url_Response x
 Where Upper(x.Output) Not Like '%SUCCESS%' 
 Group By x.Output 
 Order By 1 Desc;
```